# npm command does not show any output or result

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

[npm -v not giving any output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z5yf.png)

Please see the attached image. I have installed node js. After open my git bash, if i run node -v, its give me node version but after i write npm -v, i have passed a long time, like more than 30 minute. it is giving me any output. no error or no warning, nothing. just stay like my attached image. Here is the command also-

```
shamim@DESKTOP-3C7P5TO MINGW64 /e/wamp64/www/vuejspractice/vue-cli-dev
$ node -v
v8.9.4

shamim@DESKTOP-3C7P5TO MINGW64 /e/wamp64/www/vuejspractice/vue-cli-dev
$ npm -v
```

Same result when i run this also

```
npm install
```

Passed after a long time more than 30 minutes. nothing happen.

Please someone give me a solution.

Comment: Did you try updating your npm ? How did you install node ?

Comment: i have downloaded node from their official website. then install it to my C driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, any command that starts with npm just hangs. Apparently I accidentally set up the wrong prefix in my npm. 
The way I solved it:

1. go to your folder directory (e.g. C:/USER/)
2. ls -al
3. .npmrc folder would appear in your directory and open it in any editor
4. change your prefix back to what it was.

voila, it's back to what it was again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm init` first then carry on with `enter` to skip the questions, make sure you have a `package.json` file then try running `npm -v`

Comment: please see this screenshot https://ibb.co/gQqUBH . I run the npm init. Passed more than 15 minutes. nothing happen. Do you use skype? I can show you by sharing my screen. Please help me solve this issue. I am stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Later on I find out I set the npm config registry to local one, which was not getting connected.

So I used
npm config delete registry

After this it was working fine